# Oracle: What does the TABLE syntax do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking at a script that has the following:

```
select * from table (schema.package.function(sysdate))
```

I am familiar with:

```
select <row> from <table>
```

But I have not seen the syntax TABLE actually used before. What does it do?

Any insight would be great!

Comment: It recognizes table-valued functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TABLE keyword tells Oracle that you are not selecting from a standard table or view, but rather a function that returns results in a table like structure.

The results of the function then then be treated just as through they were a table as far as the rest of the query is concerned.

The function must be defined in a specific way for this to work.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now, thank you! Also, thank you for the link, I'll take a read through it.

Answer (score 3):

It is [a table collection expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2104990):

> The *table_collection_expression* lets you inform Oracle that the value of *collection_expression* should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The *collection_expression* can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is nested table or varray. This process of extracting the elements of a collection is called **collection unnesting**.

It may be a function, as @James said as you encountered it in the code in your question, but can also be other things. The examples in the documentation linked to above show it being applied to nested table columns in a table, for example. And you can use and unnest your own collection type, or a built-in one, e.g.:

```
select *
from table (sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5));

Result Sequence
---------------
              1
              2
              3
              4
              5
```